# Does spring saml library support multiple signing certificate for expired certificate rollover?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am having trouble finding out whether the spring saml library support multiple signing certificate for expired certificate rollover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does, you can find more details in the [Security Profiles chapter](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x/reference/html/security.html#configuration-security-profiles).

In MetaIOP mode system will use all certificates declared in the IDP's metadata, or explicitly stated as signing key in ExtendedMetadata, until it can verify the signature.

In PKIX mode system will verify the signature against trusted anchors (root certification authorities and intermediate certification authorities), so the actual signing key can be changed freely with no need for change in configuration.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this? I am able to put two keydescriptors of the `signing` signature but my IDP will not accept metadata with two `encryption` keydescriptors.

Answer (score 3):

We've recently run into this same problem and we've developed a small extension to the Spring Security SAML library to support certificate rollover.

You can check it out at: https://github.com/PaddyPowerBetfair/SpringSecuritySAMLKeysRollover